# redirect single image from one directory to another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one website, say www.example.com. So when I access "http://www.example.com/program/resources/foo.gif" it serves me `foo.gif` image from `/usr/share/roundcube/program/resources/foo.gif`, I found that in access log.

So what I would like to do is, I would like to copy that image from `/usr/share/roundcube/program/resources/` to my webroot `/var/www/www.example.com/webroot/img/` and write rewrite rule so that when request comes for `foo.gif`, it should serve from `/var/www/www.example.com/webroot/img` not from `/usr/share/roundcube/program/resources/`.

I've tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /program/resources/(.*) /img/$1 [L]
```

It's working fine. But what if I want to make a rule for single image that is `foo.gif` ?

Comment: Instead of `.*` pattern, put the filename: `foo\.gif`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 No, it doesn't work. It gives me 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it more generic and simpler than that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/override%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* override/$0 [L,NS]
```

Now just put any file you *don't* want to come from RoundCube into the override folder, e.g. `override/program/resources/foo.gif`